# Can Bessel functions be represented as a single function with two variables?

Tags: complex-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, bessel-functions

The typical way to represent a Bessel function of first kind is $ J_{\alpha}(z)$, i.e. $ J_{\alpha}: \mathbb{C}\to \mathbb{C}$.

Is there any good reason that prevents us to write it as a function of two variables $J(\alpha,z)$, i.e. $ J: \mathbb{C}^2\to \mathbb{C}$ ?

Comment: The Maple version looks like this: `BesselJ(a, z)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there is nothing to prevent considering $J_\alpha(z)$ as a function of both $\alpha$ and $z$.  However, not quite on $\mathbb C^2$: it has a branch point at $z=0$ if $\alpha$ is not an integer.

Comment: So, if I always see it written as a function of just one variable is just because of convention?

Comment: @AlessandroZunino : It is also easier to write the defining ODE for a function of a single variable with a parameter. In the two-variable form it would be a PDE where the $z$ derivatives are now partial derivatives.

Comment: @LutzL Turning the Bessel differential equations from ODE to PDE does change the solutions or the way to obtain them? In theory no, so why should be easier to consider $\alpha$ a fixed parameter?

Comment: @AlessandroZunino : It makes the topic *look* more complicated, as PDE theory in general is more complex than ODE theory, and the question is about optics, of mixing old-style and modern-style variable positioning. $α$ is a fixed parameter in the Bessel equation, I'm not sure what that has to do with this styling problem.

Comment: It's not "really" a PDE, since the derivatives are only with respect to $z$, not $\alpha$.  It's still just an ODE with a parameter.

Answer (score 1):

It depends very much on the context:

- In physics, Bessel functions often appear in problems with cylindrical or spherical symmetry where $z$ plays the role of appropriate radial coordinate.  The parameter $\alpha$ is usually fixed by some quantization condition but is not directly related to physical coordinates.
- In the theory of linear ODEs with rational coefficients, the Bessel equation corresponds to a model rank 2 system with prescribed structure of singularities on the Riemann sphere $\mathbb C\mathbb P^1$ (one regular and one ramified irregular singularity of Poincaré rank 1). Here $z$ corresponds to a canonical coordinate on $\mathbb C\mathbb P^1$ whereas $\alpha$ encodes monodromy properties of the system. So again, the nature of the two parameters is rather different.
- On the other hand, in addition to 2nd order differential equation w.r.t. $z$, Bessel function also satisfies 2nd order difference equation (recurrence relation) w.r.t. $\alpha$. It is possible to think of these equations in the same way. However, in order to see the analogy between $z$ and $\alpha$ more clearly, one needs to discretize the first parameter and go into the world of $q$-special functions.

Comment: The context, in my case, is Physics. The problem I am facing makes use of Bessel function in which both $z$ and $\alpha$ have a deep physical meaning and they are both variable (just $\alpha$ is constrained to be an integer).

Can you please explain better your last point? I am very interested in understanding this analogy between $z$ and $\alpha$ (I admit I don't know a lot about $q$-special functions).

Comment: @AlessandroZunino The recurrence relation for Bessel function involves $J_\alpha$ ,$J_{\alpha+1}$ and $J_{\alpha-1}$. Imagine that $\alpha$ is very large so that its shifts by $\pm1$ can be considered as small. One could also imagine that after appropriate scaling, the recurrence relation could then become a 2nd order differential equation. Now what one should do is actually the inverse of this procedure: guess a recurrence relation in the appropriately rescaled variable $z$ which gives the Bessel equation in the limit.